# Java Reg accepts * which is not in [0-9]*[ -/]{0,1}[0-9]* - is it a bug?

Tags: java, regex

The following RegEx  `[0-9]*[ -/]{0,1}[0-9]*` matches e.g. `1*2`.

The * is not defined in my regex and not intended; the space before - needs not to be escaped (as far as I found out)

If I only use two character of `[ -/]`,  `1*2` do not match.

When I change the order e.g. to `[0-9]*[-/ ]{0,1}[0-9]*`, `1*2` is not matching (like expected).

Do I miss something or is this a bug?

I have this behaviour with Java 7 and on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

**Update** 
The RegEx is used in the Bean Validation @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]*[ -/]{0,1}[0-9]*").

Comment: Please, show us the code using the regex you mentioned.

Comment: The reason is the hyphen in the character class. It creates a range from a space up to `/`. There's been a lot of this on SO.

Comment: no reason to downvote question, beter explain where it goes wrong. Else there is no reason for this site to exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[ -/]` is a character class, and in a character class, `-` is the range operator. "any character in the range of characters from 'space' to 'slash', inclusive".

That means it uses the ASCII table (basically) to match the characters `[space]`, `!`, `"`, `#`, `$` etc... up to `/`.

However, ranges only work in a postive direction: from a low ASCII code to a high ASCII code. When you go high->low, the range doesn't apply, and it's looking for only 3 characters: `[space]`, `dash` and `slash`.

E.g. in an easier to read example:

```
ascending:    [b-g] -> matches 'b', 'c, 'd', 'e', 'f', or 'g'
descending:   [g-b] -> matches ONLY 'g', '-', or 'b'
```

Comment: Sound feasible and makes sense with this explanation. Thank

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason is due to the hyphen.

The section `[ -/]` is actually creating a range from space to `/`.

Answer (score 2):

you have `[ -/]` means any char, between space and  slash. (ascii 32 - 47). `*` has ascii `42`, that's why `1*2` was matched.

If you want to match only `- or / or SPACE` , use `[-/ ]`, put the `-` at the beginning in the character class.

Comment: waiting to learn from the downvote, please leave a comment.